# How to display jQuery.show() in animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this code when I click button DIV displays like flipping from top left.

```
$( "#mybutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#mydiv" ).show("slow");
});

<input type="submit" value="click" id="mybutton" />
<div id="mydiv" style="height:50px; width:50px; background-color:#000; display:none;">test</div>
```

How can I get same kind of effect in the following scenario?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.showim = function(src) {
    $("#divcont1").html(src);
  };
});
```

I tried like **But it didn't work**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.showim = function(src) {
    $("#divcont1").html(src).show('slow');
  };
});
```

HTML code

```
<span class="spcusr" onclick="showim('<h1>I should be displayed now</h1>');">PARIS</span>
<div id="divcont1"></div>
```

Comment: @Anton - Sorry, didn't notice while copying it from my source files. Unfortunately still not working.

Comment: i checked, .show('slow') is correct ,check console! you have an error in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the script you expecting? Forgive me if this is wrong,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 window.showim = function(src) {
   $("#divcont1").hide().html(src).show('slow');
 };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divcont1").html(src).slideToggle();
```

or

```
$("#divcont1").html(src).slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery animate api:  [.animate() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)